# Query in looping through JSON data set in getting front-end output

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am using this JSON data and I am suppoose to get the output as the first line will contain "EPL-2015". The second as "Match Day 1". The third line as "Date" and the fourth line as "Team1 VS Team2". But I am getting only correct output in line 1 and I am not getting rest of the outputs. Please help me in getting the rest.I think I am doing wrong in looping through the data of JSON.

```
var myApp = angular.module('futsalApp', []); 

myApp.controller('futsalController', function($scope) {

  $scope.fixtures = 
  {
       "name": "EPL-2015",
       "rounds":
       [ 
       {
        "name": "Match Day 1",
        "matches": 
        [
        { 
          "date": "2015-08-08",
          "team1":
          { 
            "key": "manutd",
            "name": "Manchester United",
            "code": "MUN"
          },

          "team2":
          {
            "key": "tottenham",
            "name": "Tottenham Hotspur",
            "code": "TOT"
          },
          "score1": 1,
          "score2": 0
        },

        {
          "date": "2015-08-08",
          "team1":
          {
            "key": "bournemouth",
            "name": "Bournemouth",
            "code": "BOU"
          },
          "team2": 
          {
            "key": "astonvilla",
            "name": "Aston Villa",
            "code": "AVL"
          },
          "score1": 0,
          "score2": 1
        }
      ]
      }
      ]
    }

})
```

.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <div class="fixtures-first" ng-repeat="fix in fixtures">
      <a>
        <h2 class="match-title"> {{fixtures.name}} </h2>
        <p class="match-day"> {{fixtures.rounds.name}} </p>
        <p class="match-day"> {{fixtures.rounds.matches.date}} </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please, show the logic you are trying to implement. This way, we can see how to get the right output.

Comment: Yes sure. Actually I am beginner in learning Angular. That's why I am not getting these small things.

Comment: '    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="fixtures-first" ng-repeat="fix in fixtures">
          
            <a>
            <h2 class="match-title">
              {{fixtures.name}}
            </h2>
            <p class="match-day">
              {{fixtures.rounds.name}}
            </p>
            <p class="match-day">
              {{fixtures.rounds.matches.date}}
            </p>
          </a>

        </div>
     </div>
    </div>'

Comment: `<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
      <div class="fixtures-first" ng-repeat="fix in fixtures">
          
            <a>
            <h2 class="match-title">
              {{fixtures.name}}
            </h2>
            <p class="match-day">
              {{fixtures.rounds.name}}
            </p>
            <p class="match-day">
              {{fixtures.rounds.matches.date}}
            </p>
          </a>

        </div>
     </div>
    </div>`

Comment: Wich output are you waitting?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems. In this line:

```
<div class="fixtures-first" ng-repeat="fix in fixtures">
```

...you're not setting your loop correctly. `fixtures` is a Javascript object, not an array, so you're not looping the way you want. You also never use `fix` for anything, so I think you've misunderstood how to use `ng-repeat`.

What you probably mean to do is repeat over your `matches` array, which is an actual array. Below, note that `fixtures.rounds[0]` is the first element of your `rounds` array.

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2"> 
        <div class="fixtures-first" ng-repeat="match in fixtures.rounds[0].matches"> 
            <a> 
               <h2 class="match-title"> {{fixtures.name}} </h2> 
               <p class="round-name"> {{fixtures.round[0].name}} </p> 
               <p class="match-day"> {{match.date}} </p> 
            </a> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have one more doubt now. Here you have used rounds[0]. Suppose we have around 10 rounds and we have to display all the fixture in the same manner that I have told above. Then what I have to do? I think i have to use nested ng-repeat, but how to do that?

Comment: Just nest them inside each other, e.g. `<div ng-repeat="round in fixtures.rounds"><div ng-repeat="match in round.matches">{{ round.name }}{{ match.date }}</div></div>`